# Bytes with escape for re module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

```py
import re

a = 0xf27f28d7
b = a.to_bytes(4, 'little')
with open(fimage, 'rb') as f:
  print([hex(m.start(0)] for m in re.finditer(b, f.read()))

# b = b'\xd7(\x7f\xf2'
```

above code return error:

> missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1

I know the bytes includes a `(`. It should be `\(`. How to convert to byte to ensure no error with escape?
I am using Python 3.6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `b = b'....'` in your code, which doesn't make your question understandable. Please extract a [mcve] and provide that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your bytes somehow like that

```py
b = b'\xd7(\x7f\xf2'
b = ''.join(['\\x'+hex(c)[2:] for c in b]).encode()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), but it will also escape bytes that don't correspond to printable characters, so you'll need to filter them out.

```
import re

b = b'\xd7(\x7f\xf2'

k = []
for i in b:
    i_bytes = bytes([i])
    if i < 0x80 and chr(i).isprintable():
        i_bytes = re.escape(i_bytes)
    k.append(i_bytes)
print(b''.join(k))  # -> b'\xd7\\(\x7f\xf2'
```

I'm sure this code could be improved, just not sure how.